# Combining row values from multiple tables into one result cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I'm looking to create a report of sorts and am having a hard time wrapping my head around how this portion could be done with a single select in SQL (my experience is limited to a database course and some working knowledge - more of a front end dev).

I should mention that joining the question table and question tag bindings/tags table isn't an issue for me - what I can't wrap my head around is how multiple values could be added to the same result cell without multiple nasty T-SQL loops.

Any tips on how to get started would be a huge help.

Table 1: Question  Table

```
ID  Content  CategoryName        
---------------------------     
1   ABC      Q1               
2   DEF      Q3               
3   GEH      Q3
```

Table 2: Tag Table

```
Tag Id            Tag Name
---------------------------------
4                 Dream
5                 Light
6                 Recover
```

Table 3: Question Tag Bindings

```
BoundQuestion ID   BoundTagId
---------------------------------
1                  4
2                  5
3                  6
3                  4
```

Desired Result Table (Question table with added Tags column)

```
ID  Content  CategoryName   Tags     
----------------------------------------     
1     ABC      Q1           Dream    
2     DEF      Q3           Light    
3     GEH      Q3           Recover, Light
```

Thanks to anybody who looks at this, hope you're all staying safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join the three tables and aggregate to generate tag list. I guess that a lateral join should also be an efficient option here, since it avoids outer aggregation:

```
select q.*, t.*
from questions q
outer apply(
    select string_agg(tag_name, ', ') tags
    from questionTags qt
    inner join tags t on t.TagID = qt.BoundTagID
    where qt.BoundQuestionID = q.ID
) t
```

Note that `string_agg()` was added in SQL Server 2017.

In earlier versions, we can resort the `for xml path` solution:

```
select 
    q.*, 
    stuff(
        (
            ', ' + tag_name tags
            from questionTags qt
            inner join tags t on t.TagID = qt.BoundTagID
            where qt.BoundQuestionID = q.ID
            order by tag_name
            for xml path('') 
        ), 
        1, 2, ''
    ) tags
from questions q
```